Fully faithful embeddings of derived category of projective space into derived category of a higher dimensional projective space
Let $N>n$. Are there are any known cases of a fully faithful embedding $D^b(\mathbb{P}^n) \hookrightarrow D^b(\mathbb{P}^N)$?

Embedding as what? As triangulated categories or their DG enhancements?

@Z.M As triangulated categories.

I would guess that that there are no such embeddings. Here is a sketch of proof.
On the one hand, every exceptional object on $\mathbb{P}^N$ is $\mathrm{SL}_{N+1}$-equivariant, hence the space of morphisms between two such objects is a representation of $\mathrm{SL}_{N+1}$.
On the other hand, the space of maps between two simplest exceptional objects on $\mathbb{P}^n$ has dimension $n+1$, while the minimal non-trivial representation of $\mathrm{SL}_{N+1}$ has dimension $N+1$.
So, the only remaining thing is to show that one cannot have an exceptional collection where all morphisms spaces are trivial representations of $\mathrm{SL}_{N+1}$.
